# Do have the elements of a sigma algebra generated by an algebra a countable cover from the algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

Let be $X$ a set and $\mathcal{A}$ an algebra on $X$ and $\mathcal{M}$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$.

Is the following claim true? Hint for the proof?

> For all $S\in\mathcal{M}$, there is a sequence $(S_k)$ in $\mathcal{A}$ such that $S\subseteq \bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}S_k$.